# Can DynamoDb streams eventId be used as primary key?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a usecase to process dynamodb streams and ingest the data in Redshift for data warehousing and analytics. I want to ensure that there exists only one record per dynamodb update and there are no duplicates. Can I use eventId present in DynamoDb streams record as primary key in Redshift table?

I know dynamodb streams guarantees record is delivered only once but we have fan out design which may not ensure exactly once delivery at the end of flow.

I have looked at Aws docs, it says eventId is global unique identifier for a stream. But, want to understand from anyone who used eventId for such usecase and had success.

Comment: It's a unique id, what success are you wanting to hear? Do you have a specific concern or question?

Comment: I understand it's unique so it could be used as primary key, right? Or am I trying to design something weird. I am expenting someone answer like, "hey we are using it and have no issues?" Or "hey, we used it. It works but these are caveats!"

Comment: It's a unique id, use it or generate your own but the result will be the same. If you require a unique id for every event then why not use it if it suits your needs.